# Why can't I access AWS ECR from AWS Batch?

Tags: terraform, subnet, amazon-ecr, aws-security-group, aws-batch

I have created an ECR repo and Batch compute environment in AWS using the following terraform code as per the documentation I found:

```
 provider "aws" {
      version = "~> 4.19.0"
      region  = local.region
      # profile = "some_profile"
    }
    
    locals {
      region           = "eu-west-1"
    }
    
    resource "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr-training-repository" {
      name                 = "ecr-training-repository"
      image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"
    
      image_scanning_configuration {
        scan_on_push = true
      }
    
      tags = merge(
        {
          ManagedBy = "Terraform"
          Environment = "dev"
        }
      )
    }
    
    
        resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr-dkr-endpoint" {
        vpc_id       = aws_vpc.batch-vpc.id
     private_dns_enabled = true
      service_name = "com.amazonaws.${local.region}.ecr.dkr"
     vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
     security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.batch-security-group.id]
     subnet_ids = "${aws_subnet.batch-subnet-dev.*.id}"
    
    }
    
    resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr-api-endpoint" {
      vpc_id       = aws_vpc.batch-vpc.id
      service_name = "com.amazonaws.${local.region}.ecr.api"
     vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
     private_dns_enabled = true
     security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.batch-security-group-dev.id]
     subnet_ids = "${aws_subnet.batch-subnet-dev.*.id}"
    }
    
    resource "aws_ecr_lifecycle_policy" "ecr-training-repository-dev-lifecycle-policy" {
      repository = aws_ecr_repository.ecr-training-repository.name
      policy = <<EOF
    {
        "rules": [
            {
                "rulePriority": 1,
                "description": "Expire images older than 14 days",
                "selection": {
                    "tagStatus": "any",
                    "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
                    "countUnit": "days",
                    "countNumber": 14
                },
                "action": {
                    "type": "expire"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
    }
    
    data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2-assume-role" {
      statement {
        effect = "Allow"
    
        principals {
          type        = "Service"
          identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
        }
    
        actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-instance-role" {
      name               = "ecs_instance_role"
      assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2-assume-role.json
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_instance_role" {
      role       = aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.name
      policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs-instance-role" {
      name = "ecs_instance_role"
      role = aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.name
    }
    
    data "aws_iam_policy_document" "batch-assume-role" {
      statement {
        effect = "Allow"
    
        principals {
          type        = "Service"
          identifiers = ["batch.amazonaws.com"]
        }
    
        actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role" "aws-batch-service-role" {
      name               = "aws_batch_service_role"
      assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.batch-assume-role.json
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws-batch-service-role" {
      role       = aws_iam_role.aws-batch-service-role.name
      policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole"
    }
    
    resource "aws_security_group" "batch-security-group" {
      name = "aws_batch_compute_environment_security_group"
    
      vpc_id  = aws_vpc.batch-vpc.id
    
      egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_vpc" "batch-vpc" {
      cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
    }
    
        resource "aws_subnet" "batch-subnet" {
      vpc_id     = aws_vpc.batch-vpc.id
      cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
    }
    
    
    resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "batch-compute-environment-sample" {
      compute_environment_name = "sample"
    
      compute_resources {
        max_vcpus = 4
        min_vcpus = 0
    
        security_group_ids = [
          aws_security_group.batch-security-group.id
        ]
    
        subnets = [
          aws_subnet.batch-subnet.id
        ]
    
        type = "FARGATE"
      }
    
      service_role = aws_iam_role.aws-batch-service-role.arn
      type         = "MANAGED"
      depends_on   = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws-batch-service-role]
    }
```

I have managed to push a docker image to the repo via the aws cli, and have created a batch job definition which runs the image. When I try to run the job, however, I get the following error:

*ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retrieved 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr .##-###-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 63.34.60.177:###: i/o timeout. Please check your task network configuration.*

I've found suggestions that it might be a misconfigured security group or subnet, but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure if the ECR has to be included in the security group and if that would affect my ability to push images via the aws cli.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the VPC/subnet you are using are private, and there likely isn't a NAT gateway so the job isn't able to talk to the ECR service. You should consider deploying a VPC endpoint for ECR, which will allow communication to the service without internet connectivity

Comment: @Paolo thanks, any chance you could share a link or an example?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html